# Salesforce Experience Cloud Just in Time Provision error

Tags: saml, jit-handler, jit

In our org Single Sign on is working but Just in time giving following error for new Users.

Below is assertion details shown on SSO.

```
Unexpected Exceptions
  Ok
1. Validating the Status
  Ok
2. Looking for an Authentication Statement
  Ok
3. Looking for a Conditions statement
  Ok
4. Checking that the timestamps in the assertion are valid
  Timestamp of the response is outside of allowed time window
  Current time is: 2021-03-29T10:49:41.620Z
  Timestamp is: 2021-03-29T10:37:40.175Z
  Allowed skew in milliseconds is 480000
  Timestamp of the assertion is outside of allowed time window
  Current time is: 2021-03-29T10:49:41.620Z
  Timestamp is: 2021-03-29T10:37:40.170Z
  Allowed skew in milliseconds is 480000
5. Checking that the Attribute namespace matches, if provided
  Not Provided
6. Miscellaneous format confirmations
  The InResponseTo value is invalid or expired
7. Confirming Issuer matches
  Response's issuer did not match the issuer configured in the Single Sign-On Setting
  Issuer from assertion: https://sts.windows.net/2bb82c64-2eb1-43f7-8862-fdc1d2333b50/
  Issuer from your settings: https://test.lightning.force.com/
  Assertion's issuer did not match the issuer configured in the Single Sign-On Setting
  Issuer from assertion: https://sts.windows.net/2bb82c64-2eb1-43f7-8862-fdc1d2333b50/
  Issuer from your settings: https://test.lightning.force.com/
8. Confirming a Subject Confirmation was provided and contains valid timestamps
  Ok
9. Checking that the Audience matches
  Ok
10. Checking the Recipient
  Ok
11. Validating the Signature
  Is the response signed? false
  Is the assertion signed? true
  The reference in the assertion signature is valid
  Signature or certificate problems
  The signature in the assertion is not valid
  Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? false
12. Checking that the Site URL Attribute contains a valid site url, if provided
  Not Provided
13. Looking for portal and Organization ID, if provided
  Not Provided
14. Checking if session security level is valid, if provided
  Ok

Subject: TEST_APIPORTAL@test.com
Unable to map the subject to a Salesforce user

AssertionId: _fa4842a6-c28d-4983-83fe-ad8c64113f00
```

Comment: have you tried doing JIP by yourself, what is your JIP handler?

Comment: Have you made sure all the SAML setting are OK? are any of the certificates expired by any chance?